# Primefaces (NullPointerException)

Tags: primefaces, nullpointerexception

Here's the problem.
I want to use primefaces, on server (using Glassfish 3.x) code, seems to be ok, but after running, i get this NPE error.
And cant figure out, where its coming from..

my Bean:

```java
package mybean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;


@ManagedBean(name = "chartBean")
@RequestScoped

public class ChartBean {

    private PieChartModel model;

    public ChartBean() {
        model = new PieChartModel();
        model.set("Brand 1", 540);
        model.set("Brand 2", 325);
        model.set("Brand 3", 702);
        model.set("Brand 4", 421);
        }

    public PieChartModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

And index page:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

    <h:head></h:head>
<f:view>
  <h:form>
    <h:outputText value="Hello My blog!!" />
    <h:inputText value="#{helloMyBlog.webFramework}" />
    <p:editor />
    <p:calendar navigator="true" pages="4"/>
    <p:pieChart value="#{chartBean.model}" />
   </h:form>
</f:view>
</html>
```

What can cause NPE? (Note, whole page cant be rendered because of this)

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the stackTrace and point out the exact lines of your code which throws the NPE!

Comment: how about placing the `<h:form>` inside `h:body` ? also try to check if it works with `SessionScoped` instead of `RequestScoped`

Comment: Please, post the StackTrace, only this way we can help you!

Comment: I think HelloMyBlog should be the Error. post it or check it if in that webFramework is initialized and memory is allocated to it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have helloMyBlog bean with accessible webFramework?
Your getter for PieChartModel wont return chart, maybe you should call ChartBean() in it and return it's value.